# Django forms error when submit

Tags: django

When I click add in form  the name sort as a false in database

What can I do to avoid this problem?

views :

```
def addTeam(request) :
    team1=team()
    team1.name=request.POST['name']
    team1.logo = request.POST['logo']
    team1.save()

    return redirect("https://www.google.ps")
```

urls :

```
url(r'^add/$', views.addTeam, name='team-add')
```

form as a modal ::

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add team</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
          <label for="name">  </label>  <br>
          <input type="text" name="logo" id="logo">
          <label for="logo">  </label>  <br>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
          dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <a href="{% url 'team-add' %}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-
          default" >add</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need to see `team()` definition

Comment: def teams(request) :
    all_teams=team.objects.all()

Comment: I don't think this is `team()` you use in `addTeam`. Also, add it to question

Comment: team this  is a model i create it   and i need to add another team when click to add  ,  i use this to add .

Comment: What is the exact error ?? Can you post the error with it's traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to post form on click of add button, But you are using `<a>` tag for posting the data. `<a>` tag will always redirects the specified url, but not post the data.

So, for posting the data, give the url in `<form>` tag, like below:

```
<form actions="{% url 'team-add' %}">
```

and put `<button>` tag inside the `<form>` tag

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-
          default" >add</button>
```

and make the `<button>` tag type as `type="submit"`.

So, that the code will look like below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add team</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{% url 'team-add' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                <label for="name">  </label>  <br>
                <input type="text" name="logo" id="logo">
                <label for="logo">  </label>  <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-
                    default" >add</button></a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
                dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```